# Remove duplicates from foreach

Tags: php, duplicates

I'm trying to loop through a custom post type and display all meta values for a meta key.

I'm able to display all the values, however there are some duplicates. I want to remove those duplicates.

I have tried using `array_unique` without luck.

My code:

```
 <?php
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'lejlighed'

 ));
 ?>
               <?php
while (have_posts()):
the_post();


$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'antal_varelser');

foreach ($meta as $m) {

    echo '<option value="1">' . $m . '</option>';

}
endwhile;
?>
```

The result:
2
2
3
4
3
3
4

Any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, this [isn't a WordPress specific question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so I'm going to close vote it, ask PHP specific questions on [so]. Secondly, don't use `query_posts`, you can find the explanation for the why on [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534). Thirdly, to help you out anyway, use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to have only unique values.

Comment: Ok - If you had read my question i stated that I already have tried using ´array_unique´. I will post this on stackoverflow. And good explanation on why i shouldn't use query_posts  - really helpful...

Comment: Added the links to the threads that are explaining it. Sorry, skipped the `array_unique` part in you question somehow, but it actually changes nothing about my suggestion. Not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you. Had a look at `query_posts` and you are right. Got some good feedback on stackoverflow.